# Adding a button in one column of a table

Tags: java

I am using lwuit to create a table with some values and a row listener. in j2me.
I am trying to add a button and a listener to it so that i have a value in the table by which i can implement a row listener. I have used the following link: http://lwuit.blogspot.in/2010/06/headon-that-table.html. But when i add the button to the table it comes to the end of the table because the table model only accepts the object as its input that is added to the table.

By using this link i added the button by the button by the following command:

```
container.addComponent(new Button("Details"));
```

Also i tried to create a grid layout or a table layout and added buttons with the number rows*columns but still the listener for the last button works, not for the rest. Any ideas on how can implement this logic. My actual task is to add a row click listener to the table. Any conceptual or coding help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: For anything. The best would be providing all the relevant code. Yet you didn't provide any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mean while i got the answer for a friend which i am sharing with you. He said me to add buttons in grid or table layout and the buttons should be adding like a 2d array so that their listeners are properly managed.

```
public class Midlet extends MIDlet implements ActionListener{

Form f;
Container c;
private int ROWS=100;
Button b[][];
private int COLUMNS=3;
public void startApp() {
    Display.init(this);

    f=new Form("grid with buttons");
    c=new Container(new TableLayout(ROWS, COLUMNS));
    b=new Button[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    c.setScrollableX(true);
    c.setScrollableY(true);
    //c.setDraggable(true);
    addElements();


    //f.setScrollable(false);
    f.setScrollVisible(true);
    f.addComponent(c);
    f.show();

}

public void pauseApp() {
}

public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
}

public void addElements()
{
    for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<COLUMNS;j++)
        {
            b[i][j]=new Button(i+" sdkljf "+j);
            c.addComponent(b[i][j]);
            b[i][j].addActionListener(this);
        }
    }

}


/**
 * 
 * @param message message to be displayed
 * @param title title of the alert
 */
 public void showMsg(String message, String title)
{
    final Dialog d=new Dialog(title);
    d.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    Button b=new Button("Ok");
    TextArea msg=new TextArea(message);
    msg.setUIID(message);
    msg.setEditable(false);

    //dialogContainer.addComponent(msg);
    //dialogContainer.addComponent(b);

    d.addComponent(msg);
    d.addComponent(b);

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
             d.dispose();
        }
    });

    d.show();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<COLUMNS;j++)
        {
            if(b[i][j]==evt.getComponent())
            {
                showMsg(i+","+j, "sl;dkf;");
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```